# MySQL PHP Insert string blobs into table

Tags: php, mysql

How can I insert a literal blob into an `update` statement?

Example

`$blob = $this->runQ("SELECT myBlob FROM db1.table1 WHERE id = 1");`

`$update = $this->runQ("UPDATE db2.table1 SET myBlob = $blob WHERE id = 1");`

The second statement fails. I know for a fact I have the blob contained in `$blob` via `echo`, but I don't know how to use it in the update command.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing single quotes for blob

```
$update = $this->runQ("UPDATE db2.table1 SET myBlob = '$blob' WHERE id = 1");
```

Comment: Thanks.. no luck. I've tried `set myBlob = NULL` just to make sure it's working. It gets set to null.  I've also echoed the real query, and it looks like it should. `UPDATE db2.table1 SET mBlob = `"ePNG ... etc... ` WHERE id = 1` MySQL then says `Invalid Parameter number: no parameters bound.` I'm using PDO but not binding anything here, and using NULL works...

Comment: Then when I try a more complex blob, I get - mixed named and positional parameters. I can use any other value than a blob and its fine, but it's just not liking the blob.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using PDO parameters instead, as I could never get the blob to work in a string query.

`$update = $this->runQ("UPDATE db2.table1 SET myBlob = :blob WHERE id = 1");`

`$this->bindParam(':blob', $blob);`